# BufferedImage drawn to JPanel before its compltely drawn in Java

Tags: java, animation, graphics, drawing, drawimage

I cant find any answer to  this. I am trying to use active painting in loop in Java. I create a new `BufferedImage` and in my paint method get its graphics, draw to its graphics normal `Image` and also various shapes like `fillRect() etc.` Then I draw the `BufferedImage` to `JPanel`  (with variable name *canvas*) graphics.

```
Graphics gr = buffer.createGraphics();
gr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500, 500, null);

for (int i = 0; i<200; i++){        
gr.drawOval(i*10,i*20,50,50);
etc.
}

gr.dispose();
canvas.getGraphics().drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, 500, 500, null);
```

Why do I see in the JPanel all the shapes drawn but without Image , which comes only with delay  I thought that first everything is drawn to BufferedImage and that is subsequently drawn on another graphics at once (isnt that whats buffers about?). Can someone please explain this to me? What thread is supposed to draw stuff on graphics object? In which is this Image drawing running (when using active rendering, not calling paintComponent())

Comment: don't forget to dispose the graphics you got from canvas.getGraphics()

Comment: I thought its disposed automatically or via garbage collector since I did not create reference. What is the correct command to dispose of that graphics? canvas.getGraphics().dispose();?

Comment: it is preferable to explicitly dispose of limited resources manually as the finalizer is not guaranteed to run, keep a reference from the first call and call dispose on that

Comment: Btw. isnt the return value of canvas.getGraphics() the same graphics object which is used in its paintComponent() method?

Answer (score 0):

> What thread is supposed to draw stuff on graphics object?

Any thread you want. I wrote a GIS application a while ago where I had to do this kind of operations (draw image and shapes and display them). Here is how I proceeded:

1. Have a background thread that draws the image and all the shapes into the `BufferedImage`
2. In your `JPanel.paintComponent()` get the result from the background thread and draw it into the JPanel's graphics

Running this bit of code

```
canvas.getGraphics().drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, 500, 500, null);
```

outside the `paintComponent` is really a bad idea and might explain the problems you are experiencing. This is due to the graphics you get from `canvas.getGraphics()` are not meant for rendering but only for operations such as printing

You should definitely draw your `BufferedImage` in the `JPanel.paintComponent()` method which will solve a lot of your issues

Comment: The reason I would like to use active painting outside paintComponent is to achieve stable frequency of drawing / graphics updates, which is  hard to control with paintComponent() inside event dispatch thread. I thought that active painting happens inside the thread in which I put it. But as the certain commands/lines of code are carried out ( at least visually on screen)  before the effects of the previous code ( image drawing) are visible, it makes me think that there is another thread in play again.

Comment: I see. That is unfortunately not recommended. Use `paintComponent` for now and optimize it later (don't render your graphics if the image did not change for example...)

Comment: I know that passive painting is more reliable but as I am experimenting with making a game I followed advice from some books and tutorials. What is more important I try various approaches to learn how the Java works. And the real problem for me is not the delayed image drawing but that it completely puzzles me and I cant explain why the bufferedimage is drawn on JPanel before it is completely drawn. All happening in one thread.